# How can I clean behind the electric grill element in my electric oven?

Tags: cleaning, oven

I can clean the whole of the inside of my oven but how can I clean the roof of my oven behind the electric grill element (which won't move)?

Comment: Does the oven have a self-cleaning function? (many do)

Comment: My top element is a single piece of wire that curves around the roof of the oven, can't you just spray oven cleaner around the element and wipe off the stove roof with a sponge? That's the same way I clean the bottom of the stove.